# Natural Language Generation (NLG) to describe financial balance sheet

Tags: nlg

Is there any working Natural Language Generation (NLG) system which can describe the numerical data in a financial balance sheet. If so, please provide the code/resource. I tried but couldn't find any working system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing as far as I am aware which automatically takes a spreadsheet and just describes it, without a developer having to define the process by which the data is processed to natural language.  Natural Language is incredibly complex.

The [NLG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_generation) Wikipedia article gives an overview of a common process for converting data to text.  There is also a recent [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.09902.pdf).

Your question in its current form is too vague to provide anything more than links to such resources.  It is more of a question of "How do I convert **my** data to natural language" than "How do I convert data to natural language".  It is a highly domain-specific task.